# Updating http_proxy environment variable

Tags: 12.04, proxy, environment-variables, https

I recently changed my password corresponding to my username for my proxy. Hence I updated the apt.conf and   /etc/environment files with my new password. However when I type

```
echo $http_proxy
```

or

```
env
```

which prints all the environment variables, it displays the value with old password. Similarly for socks_proxy, all_proxy.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 25):

You can change the http/https/ftp proxy environmental variables using the following commands:

```
export http_proxy='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
export https_proxy='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
export ftp_proxy='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
```

as a one-liner:

```
export {http,https,ftp}_proxy='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
```

These will not persist however, so you may wish to add it to your bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to `/etc/environment` requires a restart to take effect. First restart your computer and see if your still facing the same problem.

If the problem still exists, open your `~/.bashrc` file and add the proxy entry in this file.

For this to take effect, you have to either restart your terminal or run source `~/.bashrc`