# Dropbox not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

Dropbox is apparently installed in my Home directory. 'env' via terminal shows a line 'PWD=/home/ray/Dropbox' but I get a message about updating proxy settings when I try to run the application.
Have tried to follow the thread on [Updating http_proxy environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228530/updating-http-proxy-environment-variable) but I think I got confused!

Could someone please clarify what I need to do as I have drawings on this laptop which I want to access (via Dropbox) on my Aquaris M10 (Non-Ubuntu) M10.